# GestureRecognizer issue on the subviews

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode4, uigesturerecognizer

I am using longpress gesture on view and add button on the point where user long press, it works fine.

But I have three problems

- I am not able to apply any gesture effect on the button(in this view)
- GestureRecognizer issue on the subviews

I notice that same gesture is not applied to subviews as longpressGesture on main view then not able apply same gesture on subview (button on the main view)

As I try TapGesture on main view then in this case I am not able to use button target on the view.

Comment: Now I am using TapGesture in mainview and then target of button is not working because it is on touchUpInside ... now I apply target to button on touchDown then it works...